# I forgot to activate Track Changes in a Word document. How to highlight my edits?

Tags: microsoft-word, version-control, diff

After I saved the document and closed Word, I realised that I forgot to activate Track Changes. I have a copy of the previous revision.

How can I highlight my (too many) edits before sending the document back to a colleague who is not computer literate enough to use the common "diff" tools?

Comment: Since you are the author of the changes you can manually highlight and comment the changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a copy of the previous revision, you can use Word's "Compare documents" functionality to create a new Word document highlighting the changes you made.

For versions of Word with the ribbon, this option can be found on the Review tab, in the Compare group.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-documents-with-the-legal-blackline-option-dbfc7351-4022-43a2-a0c4-54d1898702a0

Comment: Thanks, will this also keep previous comments and tracked changes (made by previous authors) in the new document?

Comment: In 2012 it'll keep previous comments but assume all other tracked changes have been accepted. Microsoft may have resolved that for later version, I don't know I'm afraid.